# Sum $1/x$ for each $x$ in a Poisson process in $\mathbb{R}$ of intensity $dx$.

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

Let $N(\omega,A)$ denotes a Poisson random measure on $\mathbb{R}$, for $\omega$ in a probability space and $A\subset \mathbb{R}$, with intensity being the Lebesgue measure.
Then, we define a random variable:
$$
Z(\omega):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{x}\,dN(\omega,x).
$$
$Z$ represents the sum of $1/x$ for each $x$ in the Poisson process.

1. I want to show that $Z$ is well-defined, in the sense that $\int_{[-M,M]}\frac{1}{x}\,dN(\omega,x)$ converges almost surely as $M\to\infty$.
2. Also, I want to compute the characteristic function $\phi$ of $Z$, but the only results I have for doing so are only the integral of the form $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dN(\omega,x)$.

I can't figure out how to do this.
My guess is that $\frac{1}{x}\,dN(\omega,x)$ also defines another Poisson process, but I don't know how to proceed or show this.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be all the points of the Poisson process on the real line, ordered so that the sequence $S_n=|Y_n|$ is increasing. Let $S_0=0$. Basic properties of the Poisson process ensure that $\{S_n-S_{n-1}\}_{n \ge 1}$ are   i.i.d. exponential variables of mean $1/2$, so that $$S_n/n \to 1/2 \tag{*}   \quad \text{almost surely $ $ as}  \quad n \to \infty \,.$$ Observe that  $J_n=\text{sgn}(Y_n)$ are i.i.d. $\pm$ valued with mean zero, and are independent of
$S=\{S_n\}$.  The a.s. convergence of $\int_{[-M,M]}\frac{1}{x}\,dN(\omega,x)$  as $M\to\infty$, is equivalent to the a.s. convergence of the series $$\sum_n \frac1{Y_n}=\sum_n \frac{J_n}{S_n}\,. \tag{**}$$

If we condition on $S=\{S_n\}$, then by [1], the series $(**)$ converges a.s. iff
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{S_n^2} <\infty \,.$$
This inequality holds by $(*)$.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem